# How can I position button dynamatically according to page components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, button

In React application I am displaying list of images. When individual book is removed `Hide Books` button takes the place to that component.

What I am trying to achieve is `Hide Books` button should remain at the same position and should dynamatically change its position on `y axis` if whole row of books is deleted

Initial state of application

[image]

When individual book is removed -

[image]

app.js

```
return(
<div style={{ position: "relative", minHeight: "100vh" }}>
          <button
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              bottom: "",
            }}
            onClick={clearBooks}
          >
            Hide Books
          </button>
        </div>
)
```

Comment: Place the button as a sibling to the container of the book-cards. And the container of the book-cards should be a flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the button as the next sibling to the `section` of Books. Shown in the following. All I did was to move the button out of the section. You will have to style the button with padding and such for the updated layout.

```
// in index.js, BookList

  return (
    <>
    <section className="booklist">
      {booksData.map((book, index) => {
        return (
          <Book
            key={index}
            {...book}
            removeIndividualBook={removeIndividualBook}
          ></Book>
        );
      })}
    </section>
      {booksData.length === 0 ? (
        <button onClick={handleShowBook}>Show Books</button>
      ) : (
        <div style={{ position: "relative", minHeight: "100vh" }}>
          <button
            style={{
              // position: "absolute",
              // marginTop: "2350px",
              // marginLeft: "28px",
              position: "absolute",
              //left: "12%",
              bottom: "",
            }}
            onClick={clearBooks}
          >
            Hide Books
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: This is a common solution for sections. The button below it must be placed outside the section.

Answer (score 1):

could you share more of your code? maybe have a codesandox example? It seems to be a styling issue but it's hard to tell without more code.

-edit-

your button should be separated from your list of books, this is the reason why it essentially "follows" your last book card.

Try to do something like this

```
return (
  <section className='wrapper'>
    <div className='bookList'>
      {booksData.map(book => {
         //code your books here
      }
    </div>
    //then put your button out of the div
    <button onClick={function}>hide books</button>
  </section>
)
```

your CSS for the wrapper div could be something like this

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

this way you'll have the books first then the button will be displayed below the list

Comment: okay, can I add more code here?

Comment: sure, or give a go to https://codesandbox.io it's a good tool to show your full code

Comment: Hi, any updates?

Comment: @DharmishaDoshi see the above edit. please use the tick if this is the right answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked tooo. How did you figure this out?